# How to rebin a dataset to match another dataset's bins

Tags: python

I have two lists for population, popA and popB, following the age ranges given by A and B respectively:

`A=['0-19', '20-39', '40-']`

`popA = [325, 260, 168]`

`B=['0-19', '20-39', '40-']`

`popB = [25800, 31200, 26955]`

The goal is to calculate the percentage of every age group of A with respect to the corresponding age group of B. But we don't always have the same age bins in A and B, hence I need first to check if it's possible to rebin the data of one group to match the other, then sum together the corresponding
ranges. If it's not possible, throw a meaningful message.

Example where rebinning is possible:

```
    A=['0-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-']  => A=['0-19', '20-49', '50-']
    popA = [325, 260, 168, 133, 206, 189] => popA = [585, 301, 395]
    B=['0-19', '20-49', '50-']
    popB = [25800, 31200, 26955]
```

the result aspired is :

`percentages = [2.26,0.96, 1.46]`

An example where rebinning is not possible:

```
A=['0-20', '21-40', '41-59', '60-']
popA = [325, 260, 168, 266]
B=['0-19', '20-49', '50-']
popB = [25800, 31200, 26955]
```

Unfortunately, NumPy and pandas are not allowed.
So far, I was able to do this, it works for some cases but not all :

```
    def match_testing(A, popA, B, popB):
        tupleA = [tuple(map(int, filter(None, sub.split('-')))) for sub in A]
        tupleB = [tuple(map(int, filter(None, sub.split('-')))) for sub in B]
        percentages = []
        counter=0
        for i, elt in enumerate(tupleB):
            if len(elt)>1:
                upper_boundary = elt[1]
                for j in range(counter, len(tupleA)):
                    if len(tupleA[j])>1:
                        if upper_boundary == tupleA[j][1]:
                            percentages.append(round(sum(popA[counter:j+1])/popB[i]*100, 2))
                            print(percentages)
                            break
                counter=j+1
                if counter == len(tupleA):
                    return "can't rebin data, ranges don't match"
            
            else :
                percentages.append(round(sum(popA[counter:])/popB[i]*100, 2))
                print(percentages)
        return percentages
```

I don't know if there's any better approach than this?